# Types of Waswas

Tags: salat, allah, shaitan, waswasa

Salam everyone!

Can someone tell me what type of waswas are there? can they be like 'Allah won't listen to your prayers' and 'He didn't listen to you the last time too' and 'What you're worried about will happen' and 'Your mom (or someone else that i frequently worry about) will die' and then evil laughter. sometimes it happens while i'm praying & sometimes when i'm sitting idle etc

can someone be kind enough to guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Wa 3laykum As Salaam,**

I hope you are doing well. Waswasa (whispering) are thoughts that arise from an external source (i.e shayateen (evil jinn/djinn), etc.). We see from the below sources that the whisperings are not positive thoughts but negative thoughts / ill feelings towards yourself or others. These thoughts can lead people to doubt. The best thing is to keep learning the truth and enlightening your heart with the Quran and doing dhikr (remembrance of ALLAH).

**Quran**
"From the evil of the retreating whisperer" (chapter 114 verse 4)

**Hadith**
Narrated Abu Huraira:

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "ALLAH forgives my followers those (evil deeds) their souls may whisper or suggest to them as long as they do not act (on it) or speak."

(Bukhari)

**Reference**
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6664

ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) Knows Best.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

According to my personal experience these waswas are common and the best thing to do with these waswas is to ignore them.I get all tgese three waswas especially the about the death of my loved ones just ignore them